# moment js change the date portion of a datetime

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

Using the `moment.js` library say i have a `datetime` with today's date and i would like to replace only the date part of the `datetime` with another value and keep the time portion the same

I don't want to subtract or add days etc - i have a 3rd party time picker that when you select a time it creates a `datetime` that is always the current day. I need to send back to server a different `datetime` - the date is different but keep the time portion from the picker.

example code:

```
let myDate = "2019-03-15T00:00:00"
let selectedDateTime = "2019-04-04T12:30:00"
```

expected result would be:

```
"2019-03-15T12:30:00"
```

Thank you

Comment: OK so you want the day of the first date, but the time of the second date? It should be fairly easy with a tool like MomentJS. It has plenty of useful methods to [get and set](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) days, hours, minutes and seconds. All you have to do is get the time from the second date, and set it to the first date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should solve your problem:

```
let myDate = moment("2019-03-15T00:00:00")
let selectedDateTime = moment("2019-04-04T12:30:00")

selectedDateTime.date(myDate.date());
selectedDateTime.month(myDate.month());
selectedDateTime.year(myDate.year());
```

As @JeremyThille suggested, you should take a look at the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/).

Comment: `selectedDateTime.date` = `selectedDateTime.date(myDate.date());`